# Spring + Swagger: Multipart form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I'm posting a multipart form to a Spring Boot app.

E.g.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/foo", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void postFooAsMultiPart(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
    ...
}
```

Spring does a really good job of marshalling the multipart request to an object (`StandardServletMultipartResolver`).

I'm presenting the endpoint using Swagger(Springfox).  Dependencies:

- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.8.0
- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.8.0

However, it's rendering the whole body as a single field:

```
http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

...
"parameters": [
  {
    "in": "body",
    "name": "foo",
    "description": "foo",
    "required": true,
    "schema": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"
    }
  }
],
...
```

My question is:  Is it possible to get Swagger to render each of Foo's attributes as separate parameters?

*Note:  As a workaround I've used `@ApiImplicitParams` to specify all Foo's attributes at the controller level.  However I see this as more of a workaround rather than the correct solution.*

**Edit**
I've spent a bit of time following the code, and I'm pretty sure this can't be be done with the current version.  I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2401) on the GitHub repo suggesting a change.  I'll update/answer this question depending on the outcome.

Comment: It should work without having to add the `@ApiImplicitParams` annotation, if you remove the `@RequestBody` annotation I believe.

Comment: @DilipKrishnan If I do that it adds the attributes as query params and swagger sends them that way.  E.g. `{
"name": "bar",
"in": "query",
"description": "Bar description",
"required": false,
"type": "string"
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.  This was a bug.  Fixed now (in 2.9.1).

Comment: Yes, but now if you have simple fields and an upload field, you cannot add order of that fields and make them required. Do you have a solution for that?